# Can a .NET Core application on Windows trap a SIGTERM event?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-for-windows

I'm curious if a console app written in .NET Core running on Windows can intercept a SIGKILL event and basically know it's being terminated.  Here's the code I'm trying:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello from PID {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}, press CTRL+C to exit.");

        AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Unloading += context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SIGTERM received, exiting program...");
        };

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SIGINT received, exiting program...");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        };

        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally executed..");
        }

    }
```

When I run the program from the command line, I can terminate it with the CTRL+C key combination.  This will fire `CancelKeyPress` as well as `Unloading`.  If I terminate the program other ways (Using the Windows Task Manager "End Process" function, or the `Stop-Process` PowerShell command), the process simply ends without any output written to the console.

This is part of a larger goal, which is to trap a Docker container shutting down.  On Windows, the `docker stop` command will kill the main process using SIGTERM.  This behavior is configurable on Linux Docker using the `--stop-signal` or `STOPSIGNAL` features, but those things have not been implemented on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> On Windows, the docker stop command will kill the main process using SIGTERM.

[As of version `1709` (for both host and base image), Windows containers using the base image `microsoft/windowsservercore` or `microsoft/nanoserver` will send `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to the main process only.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25982#issuecomment-375105522)

[As of version `1803`, Windows containers using those base images will send `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` to *all* processes running in the container.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25982#issuecomment-375105522)

So, depending on your versions, Docker may send `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` or `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`.

These are different than the Ctrl-C signal, which is `CTRL_C_EVENT`. [.NET's `Console.CancelKeyPress` only handles `CTRL_C_EVENT` (or the closely-related `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/19c11e6e0ca21a945d16113b8e2545cd68eecb91/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L1283), so it will not be called for `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` or `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`.

> If I terminate the program other ways (Using the Windows Task Manager "End Process" function, or the Stop-Process PowerShell command), the process simply ends without any output written to the console.

It is not possible to handle all kill signals. I believe Task Manager these days tries to do a "gentle" close which in this case is probably sending `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, but it is also entirely possible to just `TerminateProcess` a process, which kills it immediately without any signals or anything.

But recognizing a Docker-initiated shutdown and responding to it is possible, since it sends a nice signal first and only terminates after a timeout.

[The .NET Runtime will recognize `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` as a process exit request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3fc245ebb90a902a36b24125d137cae9fc30e043/src/coreclr/src/vm/ceemain.cpp#L417), but since newer versions of Docker for Windows have switched to `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`, I believe that [.NET will simply not do a graceful shutdown for Windows containers anymore](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2029).

The only workaround I'm aware of is to install your own Console control event handler. I recommend [handling `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` all as just a generic "shutdown" signal](https://github.com/Faithlife/FaithlifeDockerShim/blob/04f061e82cb18dad4605d52d9612f4a8c30444da/src/Faithlife.DockerShim/Services/WindowsSignalService.cs#L30).

Comment: Tons of good info there!  So, looks like the key is trapping the shutdown event.  I'll look into the code you linked to and see if I can get it working.  Thanks!

Comment: I gave your code a shot in a Docker container and no go.  A `docker stop` command won't fire any of these events.  I think it's probably a Docker for Windows limitation..  They should send a CtrlC to the entrypoint process first, wait a few seconds, then send a kill.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: If you want to `docker stop`, then you can't allocate a pseudo-TTY. So a container can *either* be stopped with Ctrl-C (`-it` option), or it can be stopped with `docker stop` (no `-t` option).

Comment: Yea, I kinda hit a dead end with this and decided to go a different route.  Since we're building on Azure Service Fabric, we can hook into the Service Fabric lifecycle and get cancellation tokens when services are shutting down (before `docker stop` is run).  It's a total redesign of our services, but it appears to be the only reliable way to *gracefully* shut down.  I'd imagine Kubernetes has similar support.  I'll "Accept" your answer since I think it's a pretty good summary of my options.

Comment: BTW, you're right!  When I run this with `-d` then it responds to my event handler!  So, your code does work!

Comment: I do think this is a Docker bug, so [I've reported it](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5996)

Answer (score 3):

Figured I'd post the complete working code of a .NET Core console app which, when run in a Docker container (using `docker run -d`) can respond to a `docker stop` command.  Please use this only for good!

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace DockerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private enum ConsoleControlEvent : uint { CTRL_C_EVENT = 0, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2, CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6 }

        private static void ConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleControlEvent controlType)
        {
            if (controlType == ConsoleControlEvent.CTRL_C_EVENT || controlType == ConsoleControlEvent.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT ||
                controlType == ConsoleControlEvent.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Docker container is shutting down..");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        private delegate void SetConsoleCtrlHandler_HandlerRoutine(ConsoleControlEvent controlType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlHandler_HandlerRoutine handler,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool add);

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, args) => { };
            if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandler, add: true))
                throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting to be stopped.");
            Thread.Sleep(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the proof:

[image]

Most of the thanks goes to @Stephen Cleary, so go upvote his answer.  I'm no hero.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to handle gracefull shutdown inside a container, you can use Powershell with scripting (capturing SIGTERM is not trivial) to capture the shutdown signal (in a similar fashion was presented in other posts in this thread with C#).

There is an example in this entrypoint script:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/blob/master/servercore2022/setup/base/assets/entrypoint/entrypoint.ps1

As per comments from above, and from here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25982

You can have some control over the shutdown process.